# Any change to build.gradle file cause android studio to freeze with this script

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm attempting to change the generate apk name with this script, after adding these line to the app's `build.gradle` file:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
    }
}
```

any further change to the `build.gradle` file will cause android studio freeze for a while. until I remove the script.

tested on:

AS version 1.5.1 gradle plugin 1.5.0

AS version 2.0.0-beta5 gradle plugin 2.0.0-beta5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is related to use of `each`, change it to `for-in` like this:

```
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    for (output in variant.outputs) {
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace(".apk", "-${variant.versionName}.apk"))
    }
}
```

Comment: voted up because that worked but what is the reason?